# I don't understand why one of these works and the other doesn't. Please explain how I'm handling this string incorrectly

Tags: python, sql, command, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm new to Python and I thought I'd try it out by writing to a DB2 database. Python is 2.7 and is running on an iSeries. I like the idea of Python instead of RPG or CL for a variety of things I have on my todo list, so I'm starting from first principles... However I have hit a problem - I don't seem to understand how Python handles strings. Here's an example:

Please explain why:

```
db2cursor.execute('insert into trickledb.trickledb values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        ('01100158059642','1055','2012-09-12','13:30:05','0700','1','1','28010'))
```

Is totally fine, (the values are inserted into my database) but:

```
sql="'insert into trickledb.trickledb values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
    ('01100158059642','1055','2012-09-12','13:30:05','0700','1','1','28010')"
db2cursor.execute(sql)
```

Gives the error:

```
db2cursor.execute(sql)
db2.Error: SQLState: 42601, Error code: -104
Token 'insert into trickledb.trickle was not valid.
Valid tokens: ( END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD.
```

My brain hurts!

Here is my complete script - I'm pulling data out of an XML file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# (Be in -*- python -*- mode.)
import db2
from xml.dom import minidom
db2connection = db2.connect()
db2cursor = db2connection.cursor()
xmldoc = minidom.parse('test.XML')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PluSale') 
for s in itemlist :
    print s.attributes['PluCode'].value, s.attributes['TicketNumber'].value, s.attributes['Time'].value, s.attributes['Date'].value, s.attributes['StoreNumber'].value, s.attributes['PosNo'].value, s.attributes['Qty'].value, s.attributes['SequenceNbr'].value
    PluCode = s.attributes['PluCode'].value
    TicketNumber = s.attributes['TicketNumber'].value
    Time = s.attributes['Time'].value
    Date = s.attributes['Date'].value
    StoreNumber = s.attributes['StoreNumber'].value
    PosNo = s.attributes['PosNo'].value
    Qty = s.attributes['Qty'].value
    SequenceNbr = s.attributes['SequenceNbr'].value
    string = "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" %(PluCode,TicketNumber,Date,Time,StoreNumber,PosNo,Qty,SequenceNbr)
    list = [PluCode,TicketNumber,Date,Time,StoreNumber,PosNo,Qty,SequenceNbr]
    tuple = (PluCode,TicketNumber,Date,Time,StoreNumber,PosNo,Qty,SequenceNbr)
    print string
    print list
    print tuple
    db2cursor.execute ('insert into trickledb.trickledb values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple)
db2connection.commit()
db2cursor.close()
db2connection.close()
```

I've been replaceing tuple with string with list in the .execute statement parameter bit without any joy. I'm SURE it's something really simple I don't understand fully. This is a stumbling block I really want to overcome as I LOVE the idea of Python on my iSeries... Compared to RPG or CL it's soooo powerful....

Comment: Are you mixing " and ' ? It seems like there is an extra ' at the begining.

Comment: Nope! ' are required for the SQL and the " denote the start and end of the string... If i "print sql" it looks how I expect. The bit you are looking at is: 'insert into trickledb.trickledb values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' - the single quote is closed there. I've tried it without those quotes - get "Insert not expected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both Jon and Marcelo above, I realised I was transferring a way of working with SQL from one environment to another where it was not suitable.

With help from this resource:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/db2pylnx/db2pylnx-pdf.pdf
And Jon's comments above, I learnt that the question marks in the SQL statement are "placemarkers" for the values in the tuple following the statement. 
A very simple example would be

```
tuple = ('SOMEVALUE', 'SOME OTHER VALUE')
'SELECT * FROM WHEREEVER WHERE COLUMN1 = '?' AND COLUMN2 = '?', (TUPLE)'
```

The rest of my problem was one of my own making. I was pulling values out of a list created by minidom. The list contained UNICODE as that was what the original XML file was comprised of.

The error was "_db2.Error: Param 0: String expected." and I misunderstood that to assume that the db2 parameter should be a string. It should have been a tuple (when I changed it to be a string I got: " _db2.Error: Parameters must be a tuple or list. "

**The tuple db2 was expecting should have contained ASCII strings. Not unicode** So I modified the code to load my strings with ascii not unicode:

```
PluCode = str(s.attributes['PluCode'].value)
TicketNumber = str(s.attributes['TicketNumber'].value)
Time = str(s.attributes['Time'].value)
Date = str(s.attributes['Date'].value)
StoreNumber = str(s.attributes['StoreNumber'].value)
PosNo = str(s.attributes['PosNo'].value)
Qty = str(s.attributes['Qty'].value)
SequenceNbr = str(s.attributes['SequenceNbr'].value)
```

This made "print tuple" change from:

```
(u'01100158059642', u'1055', u'2012-09-12', u'13:30:05', u'0700', u'1', u'1', u'28010')
```

to:

```
('01100158059642', '1055', '2012-09-12', '13:30:05', '0700', '1', '1', '28010')
```

And my database was updated!

```
db2 "select * from trickledb.trickledb" 
PLUCOD         TICKETNO  DATE       TIME     STORENO  POSNO  QTY  SEQNO
-------------- --------- ---------- -------- -------- ------ ---- -----
01100158059642 1055      2012-09-12 13:30:05 0700     1      1    28010
```

Many thanks - I feel my Python learning curve is not QUITE as vertical now!

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting is something like this:

```
def foo(x, y=None): print x, y

foo(1, 2)

args = '1, 2'
foo(args)
```

In the second instance, you will end up calling `foo` with a single string parameter (`args`), which will be bound to `x`, and `y` will end up with its default value. The fact that the contents of `args` look like the parameters you passed in the first instance is immaterial. Python (along with most programming languages, for that matter) just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I thought I was calling a function with a single parameter - an SQL statement. So how can I pass a statement to this function?

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks. Unfortunately I come from a programming language that DOES work that way...

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you're passing the query string and parameters, in your second example, both are being passed as one big string (which makes no sense)..

Compare these two:

```
>>> a = '("1", "2", "3")'
>>> print len(a)
15
>>> b = ('1', '2', '3')
>>> print len(b)
3
```

`a` is just a string of characters, `b` is a `tuple` of 3 elements...

Comment: The parameters are strings in their own right, but as I've stated I'm having difficulty getting my head round how Python handles strings - when I tried using the strings in the parameters I had similar errors...

Comment: @user1844868 Yes, but they're passed as query parameters, as a tuple of strings, which can be used.... It can't handle just one bit clunky string

Comment: I think I see. I tried this: db2cursor.execute ('insert into trickledb.trickledb values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')) %(PluCode,TicketNumber,Date,Time,StoreNumber,PosNo,Qty,SequenceNbr) and get an error because I can't use % inside tuples. So I need to read up on tuples! Thanks Jon.

Comment: @user1844868 What you don't want to be doing is even trying to use string formatting for building SQL queries - that's why it's `.execute(query, params)` so the escaping etc... gets handled for you and you don't want to build one big SQL string and just put it as query....

Comment: Understood. Where params is a tuple in this particular situation, right? In CL on an iseries building a string is exactly what you would do. I have a hammer, and this looked like a nail. Thak you for introducing me to the concept of the screwdriver!

Comment: Right - tried using a tuple as a parameter, and got "Param 0: String expected." Tried using a built up string and got "_db2.Error: Parameters must be a tuple or list." Tried a list: Param 0: String expected. I think I'll use RPG.

Comment: @user1844868 Why can't you just use your first example which works, but change your params each time (ie, have `('01100158059642','1055','2012-09-12','13:30:05','0700','1','1','28010')` reflect the new row to insert...?

Comment: And how do I change the parameters each time without using strings?

Comment: @user1844868 that's fine - so what's the problem with that?

Comment: The problem is entering variables which are strings, into the SQL statement as values I want added to the database. If I hard code them into the script it works, but if I actually substitute the strings holding the values I get the errors above.

Comment: @user1844868 How are you getting the data to insert - can you expand on that in your code ?